# Is there a rate limit for the Google OAuth 2.0 API?

Tags: api, oauth-2.0

I'm considering to use https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email to get hold of the user's email address and I've seen numerous examples on how to do this in both Google's own documentation and other guides on the Internet.

However I have not been able to find any information on what the rate limits are, or if there even are any rate limits for this. The Google APIs Console lists courtesy limits for many different APIs, but nothing is mentioned about the OAuth 2.0 API.

Does anyone know if there are any limits, and if so what they are?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can say fairly certainty that **there are NO LIMITS to any of Google's Authorization API's**.

I know this because it does not state ANY LIMITS anywhere within there Authorization API's Terms of Service. In fact, the [Terms of Service itself](https://developers.google.com/accounts/terms) is very bare:

> Google Account Authentication APIs Terms of Service
>
> Last modified: April 20, 2012 By using this API, you consent to be
> bound by these terms in addition to the Google APIs Terms of Service
> ("API ToS") at https://developers.google.com/terms. Deprecation Policy
>
> Google will announce if we intend to discontinue or make backwards
> incompatible changes to this API or Service. We will use commercially
> reasonable efforts to continue to operate the Google Account
> Authentication APIs (exclusive of OAuth 2.0) without these changes
> until April 20, 2015, unless (as Google determines in its reasonable
> good faith judgment):
>
> required by law or third party relationship (including if there is a
> change in applicable law or relationship), or doing so could create a
> security risk or substantial economic or material technical burden.
> This Deprecation Policy doesn't apply to versions, features, and
> functionality labeled as "experimental."
>
> After April 20, 2015, this Deprecation Policy will not apply.

If there were to be limits, Google generally would have to put them in there ToS, so I can safely say that there are no limits.

Comment: It seems there are limits in place now. As such the confidence in this answer may mislead people..

Comment: Indeed there is limit in place now.

Answer (score 9):

This is an old question, so things have likely changed since the original reply, but Google now has ["quota restrictions based on risk level"](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9028764?hl=en) (whatever that means):

> To protect users and Google systems from abuse, applications that use
>   OAuth and Google Identity have certain quota restrictions based on the
>   risk level of the OAuth scopes an app uses. These limits include the
>   following:
>
> - A new user authorization rate limit that limits how quickly your
>     application can get new users.
> - A total new user cap. To learn more, see the [Unverified apps](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865)  page.
>
> When an application exceeds the rate
>   limit, `Error 403: rate_limit_exceeded` is displayed to users

Comment: Does this limitation on Google Cloud Platform apply to the regular Authorization API as well?

Comment: There are two dashboards: console.developers.google.com and console.cloud.google.com ‍♂️ That's confusing.

Comment: Yes, that's confusing. I _think_ the "developers" console is linked to from the "APIs" section of the "cloud" console. This definitely applies to their regular authorization API. I've seen in in the wild. A lot.

Answer (score 3):

I think there's a limit to the google oauth api endpoints. I was building an browser extension and left a recursive loop while testing. Made too many requests and got this-

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

But this limit seems to be on the end user level. When I query for the information of a different user, i receive the response just fine.